# ng2 smart table api request post method not working

Tags: angular, smart-table

Am using ng2 smart table in my angular 2 project, I need send an API request using http.post() method, I have created a Service and injected in my component and calling the post method from the API service by sending an input with the URL, am getting the following exception in my console

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'post' of undefined

**My APIService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    public token: string;
    private endpoint: string = 'MYENDPOINT';
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    private process(response:Response) {
        let json = response.json();
        if (json && json.errorMessage) {
            throw new Error(json.errorMessage);
        }
        return json;
    }

    private processError(error: any) {
        let
            errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message : error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }


    getHeaders() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        if(this.token) {
            headers.append('Authorization', this.token);
        }
        return {
            headers: headers
        };
    }

    get(url) {
        return this
            .http
            .get(this.endpoint + url, this.getHeaders())
            .toPromise()
            .then(this.process)
            .catch(this.processError);
    }

    post(url, data) {
        return this
            .http
            .post(this.endpoint+ url, data, this.getHeaders())
            .toPromise()
            .then(this.process);
    }

    put(url, data) {
        return this
            .http
            .put(this.endpoint+ url, data, this.getHeaders())
            .toPromise()
            .then(this.process)
            .catch(this.processError);
    }

    apiURL(magazine) {
        return this.endpoint
    }

    delete(url) {
        return this
            .http
            .delete(this.endpoint+ url, this.getHeaders())
            .toPromise()
            .then(this.process)
            .catch(this.processError);
    }

    setToken(token) {
        localStorage.setItem('ssid', token);
        this.token = token;
    }

}
```

**app.Component**

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
 import { LocalDataSource } from 'ng2-smart-table';
import {ApiService} from './apiService'
import { Http } from '@angular/http/src/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'buttons',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styles: [require('./buttons.scss')],
  template: require('./buttons.html'),
})

export class Buttons extends LocalDataSource{
    busy: Promise<any>;
settings = {
    columns: {
      UNIQUE_ID: {
        title: 'Unique ID'
      },
      NAME: {
        title: 'Name'
      },
      DOB: {
        title: 'Date of Birth'
      },
      LOAN_AMOUNT: {
        title: 'Loan Amount'
      },
      STATUS:{
        title :'Status' 
      }
    }
  };
  constructor(private api:ApiService,private _router:Router) {
    super(null);
  }


   getElements(): Promise<any> {
     debugger
    let inpReq= JSON.stringify({"vendorID": 1})
    this.busy = new Promise(resolve => {});
    return this.api
        .post('http://apiservice:80/api/GetReviewList',inpReq)
        .then(data => this.data = data);
  }

  public LoadReviewScreen(){
 this._router.navigate(['pages/reviewscreen']); 
  }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, `RequestOptions`} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

please follow this pattern in you api and then try it again. because you are missing some file to import


  public Post(data: any, url: string): Observable<any> {

    let body = JSON.stringify(data);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.post(this.URL + url, body, options)
      .map(res => res.json() )
      .catch(this.handleError);

  }


private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
     console.error('web api error 1');
     console.error(error);
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error('web api error 2');
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```